# True random vs. Pseudo Random (can you pseudo-random true-randomness)

Tags: random

Ok, so this question involves a bit of a forward.  Bear with me.
There's this website random.org (and others like it) that claim to use some sort of quantum process or another to produce true random numbers.
If one were to query this site over and over and develop a massive log of true random numbers.  This log is then rearranged by a program to mix it up as randomly as it can.  Is the resulting output less random than when it started?  By how much?
Any good/cheap further reading on the subject?

Comment: Random RATIONAL numbers you mean for sure.

Comment: I believe Cosmin meant by 42. I'm sure it was just a decimal/rounding/sign error.

Comment: They will not be random for the same reason that the pseudo-random number generators on computers are not random.  That being that a mathematical formula / algorithm is being used to make the selection.

Comment: I have never heard of the term "less random".  A process is either random or not.

Comment: This question may attract better answers at math.stackexchange or stats.stackexchange. Disclaimer: I don't have any problem seeing it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reordering random numbers by a *fixed* permutation does not change the degree of randomness.

So if you have a perfect random number source, the same bits reshuffled will be equally random. This will be true if whether the "shuffle" is a fixed reordering (e.g. reversing all the bits) or a shuffle generated by a pseudo-random number generator (which is really a very obfuscated way of defining a fixed re-ordering from some initial seed).

This is provable from the underlying maths - if you reorder a set of truly independent identically distributed random variables then the resulting distribution will be the same as the one that you started with. Hence it is equally random.

However, this does not work if the shuffling is dependent on the values of the random bits in some way. If, for example, you sort the bits rather than permuting them then you won't have very good random output :-).

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on how you reorder them. If you used pseudo random function to do it the results will likely be less random. If you use the true random to reorder itself it will not be more random.

One thing that people forget is the reason to use pseudo random function over some true  random numbers is repeatedly and testing. If you get some unexpected results using pseudo random function will make looking at the possible problem easer.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a process that needs N 'random' numbers, you can take N from the site, and use them, IN THAT ORDER, and all will be well. If you reshuffle them, you will make them less random.

If you need an ongoing supply of random numbers, then the question is the relative quality of some pseudo-random juggle of these versus what would happen if you had a true random sequence.

Since, however, linux and windows both supply real random numbers by harnessing hardware entropy, why not just use those?

Comment: Well, but if you use Windows' or Linux's "real" random number generation to randomize "real" random samples, it should be just as random, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Time to call in an actual mathematician.

Comment: It wasn't for any practical reasons.  I'm just interested in the behavior of pseudo randomness!  Thanks! :)

Comment: Windows does not supply true random numbers (see - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx).  My guess is that Linus does not.

Comment: /dev/random , /dev/urandom, and I believe that the crypto API in windows does likewise.